# When using aws amplify on react to make an call to api gateway, how do i go about getting the statuscode as well?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless

My API gateway (using serverless) is setup to respond correctly:

```js
function buildResponse(statusCode, body) {
  // console.log(body);
  return {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  };
}
```

After deploying the backend to aws, I have client side using React.js with aws amplify, where I make the call:

```js
return API.post("api", "/api");
```

**The problem**
I get the token from the api call correctly, but I don't get the status code. How can I build out the api so that I can get the status code as well from API gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this from aws amplify docs under "get" for example. If you include the "response" in myInit, you will be able to get the entire axios object including the statuscode.

```js
let apiName = 'MyApiName';
let path = '/path'; 
let myInit = { // OPTIONAL
    headers: {}, // OPTIONAL
    response: true, // OPTIONAL (return the entire Axios response object instead of only response.data)
    queryStringParameters: {  // OPTIONAL
        name: 'param'
    }
}
API.get(apiName, path, myInit).then(response => {
    // Add your code here
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
});
```